# How to position inner div at the bottom of outer div without using absolute position in CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to position inner div at the bottom of outer div without using absolute position in CSS? For below piece of code only last div should be aligned at bottom (other three should be at top as it is)?

```
<div>
<div id="wrapper" class="parent" style="height:600px; border: 1px solid red;">
<div style="border: 1px solid blue;">Fist</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid blue;">Second</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid blue;">Third</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid blue;"  class="child">Needs to be at bottom</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution:

```
<div>
<div id="wrapper" class="parent" style="height:600px; border: 1px solid red; position:relative;">
<div style="border: 1px solid blue;">Fist</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid blue;">Second</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid blue;">Third</div>
<div style="border: 1px solid blue; position:absolute; bottom:0;"  class="child">Needs to be at bottom</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Position:absolute in this context positions absolute inside the containing box -- so it is not a positioning absolute to the document or the browser window.

See it in action with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fdxj1oue/

Comment: See OP at _"without using absolute position in CSS?"_

Comment: @guest271314: What you have done is absolute positioning -- My code does not. "Absolute" Positioning normally does not mean "absolute" mode, but using "absolute" values that could change from browser to browser or when the content of the div changes.

Comment: Must have misinterpreted Question , here . _"without using absolute position in CSS?"_ . Not _literal_ `position:absolute` ?

Comment: @guest271314: Position: absolute is maybe a bad name, but normally what you want to avoid are absolute values in your code, because they are prone to change.

Comment: don't want to use  position:absolute;..is there any other way?

Comment: @MadhuriLad: Can you explain, why you don't want to use it? It is totally unclear to me, what the problem with position:absolute is. The "absolute" is here meaning "absolute inside the containing block" -- so it is *not* "absolute" positioning relative to browser window.

Comment: @juergen maybe you are proud of position absolute, all of us knows how absolute position works with relative parents, but OP don't want to do by this way, so maybe because absolute positioning has some spacing problems, it can hide some content or don't shows fine in mobile. It must be used carefully.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: Might be -- but speculating about the OP's intentions does really not help. That is the reason I asked. I understood the problem different at first. Sometimes the reasons are different than some might think and to know the real reasons can help to find an optimal solution.

Comment: @juergen Use of "absolute" takes the element out of flow.  That can be a major problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use flex-box, it has a good support now in all major browsers.
http://caniuse.com/#search=Flex

Solution:

Outer container

```
#wrapper {
Display: flex;
Flex-direction: column;
}
```

Inner container

```
.child {
margin-top: auto;
}
```

it's better to use last-child pseudo selector to always select the bottom div. check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/EiyadZ/zcr6prp1/6/).